# JavaScript issue in Tapestry version update to 5.2.6 from 5.0.18

Tags: tapestry

I am updating the tapestry version from 5.0.18 to 5.2.6.

1. How can I disable loading default tapestry js files like ...(scriptaculous.js, tapestry-messages.js, tapestry-console.js, tapestry-beanvalidator.js)
2. How to fix the JS conflicts as tapestry combines the JS files(like JQuery and default 
   ones) even jQuery.noConflict(); also not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tapestry will only load these *.js files if they are needed. So if you see these files loaded, you are using components that use them. You can however override the prototype and scriptaculous files loaded by overriding the `tapestry.scriptaculous` symbol and provide your own custom scripts. See the [javascript documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/javascript.html#JavaScript-BuiltinLibraries). Or you can contribute to the stack like described [here](http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Remove-CSS-amp-JS-stacks-in-v5-3-td4578833.html).
2. Have a look at [tapestry-jquery](https://github.com/got5/tapestry5-jquery)

Comment: Thanks @joostschouten for the answer. I was using JQuery with tapestry 5.0.18. Now when I tried to update to version 5.2.6 there seems to be a lots of conflicts. I have used the old version of scriptaculous js files with 5.2.6, even through the things seems to work there are some flashing errors on the top of the screen. Your leads were really helpful, but I am not quite getting there yet..! Any idea on the flashing red error? Even in the [AppFuse tapestry demo](http://demo.appfuse.org/) I could see the same issue.

Comment: The flashing red errors are Tapestry telling you there are js exceptions caught by Tapestry. They could be anything. Please add the error message shown in the red box to your question as they will lead you to the problem. Also use Firebug or debugger alike to dubug your js code and step though it. Are you sure you have emptied your cache to make sure you don't have any old js code floating around?